# How to maintain an Edit URL and existing data in a Save action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, redirect

I have a Save method that has some additional server-side validation to it. If it fails, I want to maintain the "/Edit/id" URL in the browser so that refreshes will stay on the page. (If that's not possible in this situation, please let me know.)

Here's an abbreviated view of how I'm trying to do this right now:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(UserEditModel model) {
    try {
        repository.SaveUser(model.CopyTo());
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex) {
        // Doing this to just display it at the top of the page as it is not property-specific.
        TempData["UserError"] = ex.Message;
        // Doing this to maintain the "Edit/id" URL.
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Users", new { id = model.Id });
    }

    // Want to keep the URL on the Index page as "Users", instead of "Users/Save".
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users", new { page = model.Page });
}
```

Other than the URL, the biggest issue I'm coming across with this is that because I'm redirecting, I also lose all of the data the User already entered in the field on the failed Save attempt.

I already tried adding an optional `UserEditModel` parameter to the Edit action that would default to null, but when navigating to the Edit action from links on the page (not redirecting from the Save action), the optional Model parameter was getting defaulted to a `new UserEditModel()` instead of the default value of null I gave it in the parameter list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a `TempData` to put your data in in your controller. And in your view put some conditions if it is not null then retreive the data from the viewbag and put it back.

in your Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(UserEditModel model) {
try {
    TempData["Field1"] = model.Field1;
    TempData["Field2"] = model.Field2;
     .....
    repository.SaveUser(model.CopyTo());
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex) {
    // Doing this to just display it at the top of the page as it is not property-specific.
    TempData["UserError"] = ex.Message;
    // Doing this to maintain the "Edit/id" URL.
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Users", new { id = model.Id });
}

// Want to keep the URL on the Index page as "Users", instead of "Users/Save".
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users", new { page = model.Page });}
```

And then in your view:

```
  @{if(TempData["Field1"] != null)
    //Assign your textbox here

   else
   //your first code to display the textBox

    }
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Don't you mean `TempData` because with the Redirect, `ViewBag` and `ViewData` get cleared, correct?

Comment: That's a decent idea that I could see using. However, I'd improve on it by instead of storing the properties individually in TempData, storing the entire Model object. Then at the top of the page, in a Razor block, check if the object exists in TempData, and if it does, run a Copy method on the Model to overwrite all the properties. That way you don't need the `if/else` around each textbox.

Comment: Yeah. Better as you said.

Comment: I'll let you update your answer again with that if you want, and accept it. You get all the credit.

Comment: OK, so I just tried doing something like this, and realized something that I didn't think about before. `Model` is read-only in the Razor page. So you need to assign to the Model object before you leave your action method. My way wouldn't work. :/

Comment: I had also found it later. Which means you have to check on each `if` clause

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `[HttpGet]` action and `return View(model);` will save your data and url

```
public ActionResult Save(int id)
{ 
    return View(repository.GetUserById(id));
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(UserEditModel model) {
    try {
        repository.SaveUser(model.CopyTo());
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users", new { page = model.Page });
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex) {
        TempData["UserError"] = ex.Message; 
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: But that would have the Url be `Users/Save` after the error, correct?

Comment: It will be **Users/Save/2**

Comment: Right. That's the problem that kicked the entire thing off, with causing me to do a `Redirect` instead of just `return Edit()`. Plus, having a Save.cshtml, I'd have to duplicate all of the code in another view.

Comment: May be I do not understand you 100%